# France M2 admission

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, france, data-science

I have just finished my bachelor’s degree in maths (180 ECTS). I am currently starting my master’s degree in Data Science at the University of Luxembourg. In my first year I will accumulate 60+ ECTS.

I wanted to ask whether I would be able to apply for the M2 in IASD at PSL (a data science related M2), given I have acquired the 60 ECTS of my first year. Of course it would still depend on other factors, I would just like to know whether a transfer would be possible/feasible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Entering directly in the middle of a diploma path is usually called an *admission passerelle* in France

It is extremely dependent on the institution's policy (most of the time at this level, those will be open, but existing students will be prioritized)

You can usually easily find this information on the institution's website

For example, at Dauphine University (the PSL component) the rules for M2 are at this [link](https://dauphine.psl.eu/en/training/masters-degrees/computer-science/m2-artificial-intelligence-systems-data/admissions)

> Who can apply?

> - Students who have completed a BAC+4 degree (a four-year degree worth 240 ECTS) or equivalent at Dauphine or another university or institution of higher education in one of the following disciplines: computer science, applied mathematics with a focus on computer science and algorithmic thinking
> - Students in their last year of engineering school (or holding an engineering degree related to the program’s main areas of study)